# Troubles with dbutils.notebook.run in Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

I'm getting a error when trying to do the following. I don't have a idea what it could be...

```
jobStartTime = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z")
dbutils.notebook.run("/yptoCommon/LogPowerBI", 60, { "jobStartTime": jobStartTime, "NoteBook": "Oeps", "AllFiles": "10", "ProcessedFiles": "5", "NewRecords": "1" })
```

The error I'm getting is.

```
com.databricks.WorkflowException: com.databricks.NotebookExecutionException: FAILED --------------------------------------------------------------------------- Py4JJavaError Traceback (most recent call last) <command-4345148969112219> in <module> 1 jobStartTime = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z") ----> 2dbutils.notebook.run("/yptoCommon/LogPowerBI", 60, { "jobStartTime": jobStartTime, "NoteBook": "Oeps", "AllFiles": "10", "ProcessedFiles": "5", "NewRecords": "1" })
/local_disk0/tmp/1583836135359-0/dbutils.py in run(self, path, timeout_seconds, arguments, NotebookHandlerdatabricks_internal_cluster_spec) 134 arguments, 135 databricks_internal_cluster_spec, --> 136 self.shell.currentJobGroup) 137 138 def repr_(self):

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in call(self, *args) 1255 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command) 1256 return_value = get_return_value( -> 1257 answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name) 1258 1259 for temp_arg in temp_args:

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(a, *kw)
```

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my repro, here are my observation on the above issue.

You will receive this error message, when you have ***any errors*** in the execution of any cells in the notebook. You need to fix the errors in the cell and use "dbutils.notebook.run" to run the notebook.

**Example1: Notebook which has an error in the execution of a cell**

Here I have a notebook named "notebook2", which has an error message while executing a cell as shown below:

[image]

When I execute the notebook using "dbutils.notebook.run", I will see the same error message as yours because the notebook has error in executing a cell.

[image]

**Example2: Successfully able to execute notebook without any issue**

Now going back to the "notebook2", I will remove the cell which contains an error message.

[image]

When I execute the code using "dbutils.notebook.run", I will able to successfully able to run the command without any issue.

[image]